# Is there any site maintenance going on currently?

Tags: support, reputation

Is there some sort of cleanup / maintenance going on with the site?

Today (8-28) and yesterday, I noticed a few drops in my reputation.  The first was 18-20 points, the second was about 45.  I checked my profile, but didn't see anything to indicate a reputation change.  Likewise, no notifications came through.

If this occurs again, how would I be able to identify what's going on and what triggered the drop?

Comment: And I thought no one would notice ;)

Comment: D*^^!!!  I knew I shouldn't have crossed you, @YannisRizos  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your [profile's reputation tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/53019/glenh7?tab=reputation), if you enable it you will see that two questions you had answers on were deleted.

Past couple of days I've been doing routine cleanups, deleting closed & negatively scored questions. Most of them had no answers, I concentrated on old migration stubs, closed questions with no answers, horribly worded dupes and questions with zero voted answers, but somewhere along the way I deleted a handful of questions with positively scored answers that had pending delete votes (and no re-open votes) or were obviously unsalvageable.

Comment: Coincidentally I wrote this [related rant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145112/162704) only a few hours ago...

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I didn't know about the "show removed" option.  The two removals that affected me were definitely some low quality questions.  Thanks for taking care of that drudge work despite the negative impact to my reputation.  ;-)

Comment: Good rant, btw.

Comment: @GlenH7 No problem, it's what I do ;D (ranting and cleaning up)