# My reputation is going down, though it does not show any activity

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any site maintenance going on currently?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/is-there-any-site-maintenance-going-on-currently)

Last week, my reputation was about 550 and since then it's been decreasing down to 494, as of today. However, my profile shows no reputation changes since 3 weeks.

How can that be happening?

Comment: Well, not _strictly_ a duplicate, but my answer there answers your question. Check "show removed posts", a couple of your questions were migrated away, and two answers of yours were deleted when I deleted the questions (Closed questions are on a path to deletion - especially downvoted ones).

Comment: @YannisRizos Yes thank you that's what I did. At first, I did not scroll down to the bottom so I did not see that little box. Maybe it should be at the top.